# Is TOEFL minimum score strict in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, language-exams

I recently gave TOEFL and got 99 with only 20 in writing. However the 6.5 equivalent of IELTS corresponds to minimum 23 in writing. Do I need to redo the test?

Comment: My experience is that students with minimum TOEFL scores tend to struggle a lot with their studies because of their lack of command of English.  The TOEFL is really a test to protect you from wasting time and tuition on going to a university where you can't learn because you don't understand the language of instruction well enough.  If your TOEFL score is marginal, I suggest you postpone going to university in the UK until you have improved your English, even if your TOEFL score meets the minimum requirements.

Comment: This will depend on what program you are applying to. If studying for a PhD there may be some flexibility depending on the supervisor and department for marginal cases. But even then it would be a risk if your English ability was not sufficient to produce a dissertation of acceptable quality and defend it in a viva. There probably isn't much flexibility for undergraduate/taught masters programs since a lack of English ability could be a major hinderance to successfully completing the program.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on who is asking for it, and their regulations.

Ask them first. Some universities in the UK accepts only IELTS regardless of what else you have at hand. Others look at your overall experience, and ask for an IELTS only if they think your level may be not high enough.

Never heard of anyone asking for TOEFL in the UK, as it is an American test.